# Passing an array to a blade file and accessing its values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm just starting to learn Laravel and I'm having a small issue regarding passing values across files.

In the Routes file, I have the following function.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $data = [
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'jane@hotmail.com',
        'location' => 'London'];

    return View::make('hello')->with($data);
});
```

I'm passing the `$data` array to a file named hello.blade.php. And I want to print out all the values in this array. The problem is I can't iterate through them and output the values in it. I get the error **Undefined variable: data**.

Here's my blade file.

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')

    @foreach ($data as $item)
        <li>{{{ $item }}}</li>
    @endforeach

@stop
```

I learned that I could do something like this `return View::make('hello')->withData($data);` in the Route file and get it working. But I don't like the way of appending a variable name like `withData`.

Is there a way to pass the array variable and access it from the blade file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing a single argument that is an associative array, this tells Blade: Hey, take the keys of this array as names of variables and make their value corresponding to the key's value in the array.

That means, you now have in your view a variable `$first_name` with the value of 'Jane', a variable `$last_name` with the value of 'Doe' and so on.

This would be the same as doing

```
return View::make('hello')
    ->with('first_name', 'Jane')
    ->with('last_name', 'Doe');
```

You get the idea.

If you want to pass the array itself, you have to tell blade: Hey, take this array and make it available in the view by the given name:

```
return View::make('hello')->with('data', $data);
```

Now you have the whole array available in your view by the variable `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

Quasdunk is total right. if you are pass an array to the blade.

then you need to use foreach to loop the data like:
in your blade, you can dd($data). in my case , my return datas in the blade is:

```
  array:1 [▼
   0 => {#185 ▼ 
   +"id": 1
   +"title": "Alice."
   +"artist": "Lysanne Lang Sr."
   +"rating": 0
   +"album_id": 3
   +"created_at": "2021-02-03 23:24:05"
   +"updated_at": "2021-02-03 23:24:05"
  }
  ]
```

So you need below to display the datas value.

```
 @foreach($data as $data_value)
 {{$data_value->title}}
 @endforeach
```